# How to cache a row instead of an model instance when using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, memcached

I'm using `SQLAlchemy` with `python-memcached`.

Before actually using a real `SQLAlchemy` query, I first check if the corresponding key is cached, and in case it's not already cached I would `set` the found instance (which is a SQLAlchemy model object) in cache.

For most of my functions this is fast enough, but in functions where thousands of objects get queried, fair amount of time is spent in `cPickle.loads` for deserialising the objects.

Because serialisation and deserialisation of a tuple/dict row could be several times faster than that of an object, I'm wondering if I can somehow cache the row instead.

Comment: If you are working with Postgres and JSON, you can directly go from query to JSON, without getting into objects. You might want to read [this](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dogpile cache](http://dogpilecache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package for this.
There's even an example of usage on the [SQLAlchemy documentation website](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.dogpile_caching).

Comment: Could you please explain how I can make it cache raw tuple/dict result instead of the resulting model instance?